# Vimscript - Prevent Column From Moving When Using a Count

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings, functions, ex-mode, count

When you use a `count` to a key mapping it goes down `count` number of times and resets to column 1.
Actually it already resets to col 1 when entering the function if there is a `count`.
So I can save the current line number in a script variable, but that does not work for the column because the column is 1 if there is a `count`.
Using a loop does not really help because even if I instantly return from a function the cursor will move `count` number of times and set the col to 1.
Then I tried using the `range` keyword with a:firstline and a:lastline but the cursor still resets to col 1.
Is there a way to prevent this behavior of a `count` or a `range`?

```
map <unique> <Leader>c :call Commenter() <CR>

function Commenter()
  let s:curcol=col('.')
  let s:curlineno=line('.')

  echo "the column is " . s:curcol
  echo "the line number is " . s:curlineno

  let l:curlineno=line('.')
  echo "the current line is " . l:curlineno
  let l:curcol=col('.')
  echo "the current col is " . l:curcol

  call cursor(s:curlineno,s:curcol)

endfunction
```

Comment: Just a question, doesn't the space has an influence? ----- `map <unique> <Leader>c :call Commenter() <CR>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
Using `<c-u>` after the colon and before `call` in the key mapping prevents the effect of the count, but fortunatelly you can still read the count with `v:count` and `v:count1`. 
`map <unique> <Leader>c :<c-u>call Commenter() <CR>`

Then I made a while loop in my function with the value of v:count1.

```
map <unique> <Leader>c :<c-u>call Commenter() <CR>

let s:firstrun="true"

function Commenter() abort
  let l:i = v:count1
  while l:i>0
    if s:firstrun=="true"
      let s:startcol=col('.')
      let s:startlineno=line('.')
    endif

    let l:curlineno=line('.')
    let l:curcol=col('.')

    ...do stuff...

    if l:i==1
      call cursor(s:startlineno,s:startcol)
      let s:firstrun="true"
    else
      execute "normal j"
      let s:firstrun="false"
    endif
    let l:i-=1
  endwhile
endfunction
```